Create columns in dataframe based on previous rows with loops
I am trying to make a loop to fill in a dataframe. This is the data frame I have for now : link
I want to add columns to my dataframe based on conditions. Some of the values I want to get are the sum of the current and the precedent row in the loop. I have troubles calling the previous row in my code.
Here is my code so far :
RU=125
sumDP=0
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  df$EP<-with(df,ifelse(sumRR-etp>0,sumRR-etp,0))
  df$DP<-with(df,ifelse(sumRR-etp<0,(sumRR-etp)*-1,0))
  df$sumDP<-with(df,ifelse(DP>0,DP+sumDP[i-1],0))
  df$RU<-with(df,ifelse(DP>0,125*2.71828^(-00824-sumDP),min(sumRR-etp+RUo[i-1],125)))
  df$dRU<-with(df,ifelse(DP>0,RU[i-1]-RU,0))
  df$ETR1<-with(df,ifelse(sumRR>etp,etp,NA))
  df$ETR2<-with(df,ifelse(sumRR<etp,etp,NA))
  df$DE<-with(df,ifelse(DP>0,etp-ETR2,NA))
  df$RU_sb<-with(df,ifelse(DP>0,125*2.71828^(-00824-cumulDP),sumRR-etp+RUo[i-1]))
}

The code for the sumDP column doesn't work, and some of the following columns depend on it : link
I am very new to the world of loops so I am stuck here. I've checked and tried suggestions from similar questions in the forum but could not find my solution. What do I need to change to get the right results?
Expected result:
Thank you!
